# Javascript - переход по url с открытием новой вкладки

Tags: javascript

Добрый день.

```
window.location.href = "my.url"
```

Этот код открывает url на этой же страницы, а как сделать чтобы открывалась новая вкладка?

Спасибо.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

используйте метод open

```
window.open('http://example.com');
```

Answer (score 2):

Или же target="_blank"

Comment: Это как?

Comment: window.open("http://example.com", "_blank");