# Переход по ссылке после отправки формы (нажатия на кнопкку) с помощью PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html

сразу извиняюсь за возможно глупый вопрос. Мне нужно, чтоб после нажатия submit кнопки отправлялась форма, а после переход по ссылке. Пробовал почти все, способы перехода при нажатии на кнопку с помощью HTML не работают, сейчас предоставлю код js, html и PHP. Использовал уже все возможные способы с HTML и JS, PHP не очень владею и поэтому просто в тупую вставлял heder(()). Помогите пожалуйста, хотелось бы решить эту проблему!

```
<form>

               <!-- Hidden Required Fields -->
               <input type="hidden" name="project_name" value="LED RGB HUINYA">
               <input type="hidden" name="admin_email" value="1bizscam@gmail.com">
               <input type="hidden" name="form_subject" value="Form Subject">
               <!-- END Hidden Required Fields -->
       
               <input type="text" name="Name" placeholder="Your first name" class="form-line" required><br>
               <input type="text" name="Last name" placeholder="Your last name" class="form-line" required><br>
               <input type="text" name="Country" placeholder="Your Country / Region" class="form-line" required><br>
               <input type="text" name="State / Province / Region" placeholder="Your State / Province / Region" class="form-line" required><br>
               <input type="text" name="City" placeholder="Your city" class="form-line" required><br>
               <input type="text" name="Adress Line 1" placeholder="Adress Line 1" class="form-line" required><br>
               <input type="text" name="Adress Line 2" placeholder="Adress Line 2" class="form-line" required><br>
               <input type="text" name="ZIP / Post code" placeholder="ZIP / Post code" class="form-line" required><br>
               <input type="text" name="Telephone number" placeholder="Telephone number" class="form-line" required><br>
               <button type="submit" class="button-buy">BUY</button></a>
           </form>
```

JS код

```
$("form").submit(function() { //Change
        var th = $(this);
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "mail.php", //Change
            data: th.serialize()
        }).done(function() {
            alert("Thank you for your purchase :) Wait until you are redirected to Webmoney!");
            setTimeout(function() {
                // Done Functions
                th.trigger("reset");
            });
        }
        );
        return false;
    });
```

PHP код

```
<?php

$method = $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];

//Script Foreach
$c = true;
if ( $method === 'POST' ) {

    $project_name = trim($_POST["project_name"]);
    $admin_email  = trim($_POST["admin_email"]);
    $form_subject = trim($_POST["form_subject"]);

    foreach ( $_POST as $key => $value ) {
        if ( $value != "" && $key != "project_name" && $key != "admin_email" && $key != "form_subject" ) {
            $message .= "
            " . ( ($c = !$c) ? '<tr>':'<tr style="background-color: #f8f8f8;">' ) . "
                <td style='padding: 10px; border: #e9e9e9 1px solid;'><b>$key</b></td>
                <td style='padding: 10px; border: #e9e9e9 1px solid;'>$value</td>
            </tr>
            ";
        }
    }
} else if ( $method === 'GET' ) {

    $project_name = trim($_GET["project_name"]);
    $admin_email  = trim($_GET["admin_email"]);
    $form_subject = trim($_GET["form_subject"]);

    foreach ( $_GET as $key => $value ) {
        if ( $value != "" && $key != "project_name" && $key != "admin_email" && $key != "form_subject" ) {
            $message .= "
            " . ( ($c = !$c) ? '<tr>':'<tr style="background-color: #f8f8f8;">' ) . "
                <td style='padding: 10px; border: #e9e9e9 1px solid;'><b>$key</b></td>
                <td style='padding: 10px; border: #e9e9e9 1px solid;'>$value</td>
            </tr>
            ";
        }
    }
}

$message = "<table style='width: 100%;'>$message</table>";

function adopt($text) {
    return '=?UTF-8?B?'.Base64_encode($text).'?=';
}



$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . PHP_EOL .
"Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8" . PHP_EOL .
'From: '.adopt($project_name).' <'.$admin_email.'>' . PHP_EOL .
'Reply-To: '.$admin_email.'' . PHP_EOL;

mail($admin_email, adopt($form_subject), $message, $headers );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

надо после получения данных и вывода сообщения об этом сделать переход по нужному адресу. например вот так. хотя возможно в таймере это сделать будет лучше. это просто пример одного из вариантов кода который делает переход по адресу. либо  `window.open('http://example.com');`

```
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "mail.php", //Change
            data: th.serialize()
        }).done(function() {
            alert("Thank you for your purchase :) Wait until you are redirected to Webmoney!");
            setTimeout(function() {
                // Done Functions
                th.trigger("reset");
            });
            window.location.href = "https://ru.stackoverflow.com"
            }
        )
```

по ссылке обсуждаются разные варианты
[Javascript - переход по url с открытием новой вкладки](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/7006/javascript-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4-%D0%BF%D0%BE-url-%D1%81-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%8B%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%BA%D0%B8)

Comment: Спасибо большое, проблема решена)))))))))))))

Comment: я рад, но предлагаю изменить заголовок, хотя бы убрав оттуда php, а возможно и изменив его на js, поскольку не в php Вы переход совершаете. чтобы другие кто имеет похожую проблему не были введены в заблуждение и быстрее нашли решение.